# Which is the best way to sorting records in SSRS Report either in stored Procedure or in report itself?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I need to sort records based on the parameter selected by user in SSRS Report. This can be done by two ways 
1. we can sort in SSRS Report  itself
2. Or we can sort records in Stored procedure

I want to know which is the best way in terms of performance

Answer (score 1):

Doing the sorting directly in the stored procedure usually has the best performance, as it can be considered when generating the query execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

[image: groupproperties]

if you have rowgroup or column group in your report.you can do your own sort without storedprocedure.

Answer (score 0):

As highlighted in tip 10 here:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3659/sql-server-reporting-services-best-practices-for-performance-and-maintenance/

10: **Sort data at the T-SQL query level**

It is more efficient to sort large amounts of data at the data source than during report processing. Using an ORDER BY clause in the query can presort the data at the query level. Presorted data improves report processing time because of the way it is stored in memory. Data within child groups is automatically sorted, if you don't need sorting you can remove the sorting expression in the data region of the tablix/matrix.

If data sorted in the report then:

Impact on Report Performance - Medium

Impact on Report Maintenance - Medium

---

Tip 17 is also worth noting:

17: **Avoid using Interactive sorting in Reporting Services**

Avoid interactive sort buttons unless users require the ability to change the sort order of data in the report.